# Unhealthy targets on NLB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, nlb

I am trying to deploy a java application running on port 8081 running behind a network load balancer. Now I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the health checks are failing.

Following are the details of what I have configured -

Listener listening on port 443 (TLS), forwarding traffic to a target group on TCP port 8081.

I have checked the port on the instance by running netstat -ltpn and it shows java is running on port 8081.
So what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that firewall for port 8081 was blocked in golden AMI. Had to open it using firewall-cmd.

Answer (score 1):

NLB is using security group of the target instance, you need to whitelist the IPs of your NLB.

Rule of thumb

- If the health check is failing something wrong with instance
- If the targets are healthy then something wrong with LB.

Double-check the instance security group that should Allow traffic from `8081`.

- Try to `telnet localhost 8081` the port, sometimes port is occupied but not responding to a health check.
- Verify Health check port is correct in target group health

[image]

Note:

> If you have more than one private subnet in the same Availability
>   Zone that contains instances that need to be registered with the load
>   balancer, you only need to create one public subnet. You need only one
>   public subnet per Availability Zone; you can add the private instances
>   in all the private subnets that reside in that particular Availability
>   Zone.

Comment: Thanks @adiii however, I have kept all the same settings. Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: do one thing more, keep the instance allow from your IP and then check if responding?

Comment: what is the response of LB?

Comment: I am able to connect to the instance but not through the LB

Comment: how the instance is healhty then? is the right instance is added in target group?

Comment: do ssh to server and verify the server

Comment: I can ssh to the server and I can verify that app is running on the server as well. Its just for some reason targets are being shown as unhealthy even when I am running health checks on the port on which app is running i.e. 8081.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199704/discussion-between-adiii-and-ash-panwar).